# Ide error occured when i tried to.run the app in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

It was just running fine but after some time Android Studio stopped responding to run app button.
I keep on clicking but nothing happens.I have tried to reinstall but the problem persists.

Comment: I would say that there is most likely a bug in your app.  But we are unlikely to be able to help you with a bug in code that you haven't shown us ...

Answer (score 0):

Did You set your path of JDK toolkit if you didn't the set it.
go to properties of your pc Advanced system setting->Environment variables in users variable set

PATH : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin

Comment: it says Cannot run program "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: it was running fine previously it also showed up the set deployment window but now it doesn't do anything .